# SetInterval not Working with JQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a slider. The slider is not working, I dont know why . It just gets invoked only once.

The animate method is only invoked once. I logged the calls to Interval, the interval is called but the animate is not invoked after the first time
**

### **Update : I have solved the problem by just setting**

'margin-left': -='600px' in the animate method

### Thank you all for helping

**

**Slider2.js CSS AND HTML**

```js
function(){
  var sliderUL = $('div.slider').css('overflow','hidden').children('ul'),
   imgs = sliderUL.find('img'),
   imgWidth = imgs[0].width,
   imgLen = imgs.length;
   current = 1;

   total_img_width = imgLen * imgWidth;
   
   setInterval(function(){
    console.log("log invoked");
    sliderUL.delay(1000).animate({'margin-left': '-600px'},1000);
   },3000);
   
})();
```

```css
.slider {
 width: inherit;
 height: 300px;
 overflow: hidden;
 
}

.slider ul {
 /* width:10000px; */
 list-style: none;
 display:flex;
}

.slider li {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset=utf-8>
 <title>The Obligatory Slider</title>
 <style>
 body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
 }
 * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
 </style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="slider">
 <ul>
  
  <li><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="image"></li>
  <li><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="image"></li>
  <li><img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="image"></li>
  <li><img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="image"></li>
  <li><img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="image"></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="slider.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your IIFE doesn't look correct. The whole thing should be inside parentheses: `(function(){})();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the problem is in your code you are setting `'margin-left': '-600px'`
always so even if it is executed the margin remains same. I have modified the code little bit now it is working.

```
var count = 1;
(function(){
    var sliderUL = $('div.slider').css('overflow','hidden').children('ul'),
    imgs = sliderUL.find('img'),
    imgWidth = imgs[0].width,
    imgLen = imgs.length;
    current = 1;

    total_img_width = imgLen * imgWidth;
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log("log invoked");
        sliderUL.delay(1000).animate({'margin-left': '-'+(count*600)+'px'},1000);
        count = (count+1)%5;
        if(count == 0)
           count++;
    },3000);

})();
```

[check out the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n91mnqox/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, after first animation you are not changing the margin of the object. While it's the same margin, it's not animating. In animation completion callback, reset or reanimate the object for original margin position.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your code is intending, but I can tell you what it **is** doing...and I doubt it's something you'd want...

You're taking the parent `<ul>` element itself and animating its `left-margin` to `-600px` repeatedly every 3 seconds. And, of course, after the first time it's already **at** `-600px`...so the animation between `-600px` and `-600px` isn't particularly visually noticeable...

There doesn't seem to be any logic in there whatsoever that actually grabs each individual image and animates it, moves on to the next one, animates it, etc (i.e. what a typical slider does). You seem to make variables for the actual list of images (`imgs`), the length of that list (`imgLen`) and declare a var for tracking what index you're on (`current`)...that's all data that a slider would need to use...but you don't actually do anything that would turn that data into a slider.

The reason the slider isn't working, unfortunately, is that you haven't coded anything that would actually make a slider. This isn't a matter of a simple error that we can point out and fix...there just simply is not code that would create a slider in that program.